# Why is the file name getting replace by a JavaScript function in the address bar?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, web

A local html file, lets says its path is `/path/to/file.html`. Has the following at the start.

```
<html>

 <head>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.ico"/>
  <LINK href="1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

 </head>

<body class = "body_background">
.
.
.
```

when tries to open it in a browser using its full path:

The file name along with its extension ( `file.html` ) gets replaced by a JavaScript function.

i.e.

> file:///path/to/file.html

gets changed to the following: The file name with its extension gets replace by the function *`location`* located in *`1.js`*.

> file:///path/to/function location() { **...**

The JavaScript file has this at the beginning:

```
if(window.addEventListener) {

  window.addEventListener('load', location, false);

  }
else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', location);
```

This is happening on *`FireFox`*  and *`Safari`* not on *`Chrome`* through.

On *`Chrome`* the page gets displayed appropriately.

> ### ***This question is for a friend.***

Comment: @Diodeus Its a function!

Comment: isn't `location` a reserved javascript object/term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`location` is a reserved word in some JS implementations, as in `document.location`.

See: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: It has its *own* implementation of JavaScript that lacks this restriction.

Comment: It's not a reserved word. It's a property name, as in `window.location`.